# R clustering mclust extracting centroids

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using Mclust to cluster a dataset. After scoring each row I would like to get the centroids without passing through a loop and average the results by cluster.
Is it possible to extract the centroids by attribute by querying the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean parameter of the mclust model can be obtained by

```
mod1 = Mclust(iris[,1:4])
mod1$parameters[["mean"]]
```